# Check if an span element contains a "text" and is the last child of a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping around span elements which belongs to `"frag"` class. I wanted to detect if the frag element im currently in

1. has parent with 'cond' on its class name
   **AND**
2. that parent contains the text "if" or "else if" 
   **AND**
3. the current frag is the last child of the parent qualified at no.1 and no.2

(My system is like a code editor by the way, so i am using a contenteditable div)
Here, i wanted to detect if im on `b` which is qualified as no.1,2 and 3.

**contenteditable div** (textarea)

```
if( (b>3) && b<10)
```

**What i've done** dont mind about the loop. I dont know how to construct the condtions.

```
if( $('.frag').eq(ctr).parent().hasClass('cond') && /(?:if|else\s+if)/g.test$('.frag').eq(ctr).text() && $('.frag').eq(ctr).lastChildOfParent )
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="board">
  <div>
  <span class="frag cond">if <span class="openParen bm1">(</span> <span class="frag cond">(<span class="frag">b</span>&gt;3) </span> && <span class="frag">b</span>&lt;10 <span class="closeParen bm1">)</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE1**: added the span-wrap for the `(` and `)`. This makes `)` the last child.

**UPDATE2**: what i mean about parent is, it can be an immediate parent, a grandParent or grand grand grand parent. So that there will be no issues on text inside the contenteditable div like if( (b>3) && ((c>1)||(b<10)) )

Because when im in the fragment of the last `b` i wont find an 'if' or 'else if' in my immediate parent (b<10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have (1) and (2) ok, so for (3), try:

```
$elem.nextAll('.frag').length === 0
```

where `$elem` is the jQuery object of the element you're testing.

See: http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

So, overall, you'd want something like:

```
var $parent = $elem.parent();

if ($parent.hasClass('cond') && /^\s*(if|else\s+if)/.test($parent.text()) && !$elem.nextAll('.frag').length) {
    // do things
}
```

The only bit I'm unsure of is the regex because I wasn't 100% what you wanted. I went with **starting with** "if" or "else if".

UPDATE: If I understand your update, then try:

```
var validAncest = $elem.parents('.cond').filter(function(i){
    return /^\s*(if|else\s+if)/.test($(this).text());
});
// this finds all ancestors with class 'cond' and 
// whose containing text starts with 'if'/'else if'

if (validAncest.length && !$elem.nextAll('.frag').length) {
    // do things
}
```

UPDATE 2: And if you need to calculate the depth of a descendent within an ancestor, you can use:

```
function childDepth ($elem, $ancestor) {
    var generations = 0;

    while ($elem[0] && $elem[0] !== $ancestor[0]) {
        generations++;
        $elem = $elem.parent();
    }

    if ($elem[0]) {
        return generations;
    }
}
```

which will return 1 if `$ancestor` is the parent of `$elem`, 2 if it's the grandparent etc.; and it'll return `undefined` if `$ancestor` isn't actually an ancestor of `$elem`.

Comment: You mean $('.frag').eq(ctr).nextAll('.frag').length === 0?

Comment: @extraRice yeah, but i'd recommend you store `$('.frag').eq(ctr)` into a variable within each cycle of your loop, so you don't have to retrieve it three different times

Comment: I updated the question, the parent parent thing, can you adjust it that way?

Comment: So you're looking for it to have an ancestor that has `.cond` and contains "if"/"else if"; AND for it to be the last `.frag` child of IT'S parent?

Comment: @extraRice ok, i updated the answer with what I think you're after. I gotta run so you'll have to take it from here.

Comment: How can i search for the depth of the child, because in "if( b>0 &&(( c<10)  ||  (b<10)) )"... when im on the frag with 'b' it will already pass the 3conditions wherein it must be on the frag with 'c'.. something like the reverse of the ancestor thing

Comment: do you want me to post another question for this, to be fair with you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37491/discussion-between-extrarice-and-byossarian)

Comment: in case you are interested/available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864758/detect-if-the-frag-element-im-currently-in-is-the-youngest-son-grandson-grandgra

Comment: @extraRice you know I have a very reasonable hourly rate. ;) i'll have a look....

Answer (score 2):

to test whether is the last child

```
$('.frag').eq(ctr).is(function(){
    var $this = $(this), fragsibs = $this.siblings('.frag').addBack();
    return fragsibs.last().is(this) && /^(if|else \s+if)/.test($this.text())
});
```

Comment: last child of immediate parent?

Comment: :How will i say, if it is the last child of the parent that has "if or else if"

Comment: I updated the question, my fault i havent included the span-wrapped for ( ) that's why i cant make use of this solution.

Comment: the 3rd condition should be, the last child among the elements under class="frag" so that it should not see closeParen bm1 as the last child

Comment: logic is something like: $('.frag').eq(fragNum).is(':last-child')among elements with classname="frag"

Comment: Couldn't the regex be simplified to `(else )?if`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Sure about it? its not detecting.. let me see if its on my side