# Detect if the element im currently in is the youngest son/grandson/grandgrand son of an element

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, depth-first-search

I am looping around span elements which belongs to `frag` class. I wanted to detect if the frag element im currently in is the youngest son/grandson/grandgrand son(from left to right) of the a span element which belongs to `frag` class and belongs to `cond` class and has an "if" or "else if" in its text

**contenteditable div (textarea)**

```
if( ((b>0) && (b<10)) || b==15 )
```

**HTML equivalent**

```
<div id="board">
  <div>
  <span class="frag cond">if<span class="openParen bm1">(</span> <span class="frag cond"><span class="openParen bm2">(</span><span class="frag cond"><span class="openParen bm3">(</span><span class="frag">b</span>&gt;0<span class="closeParen bm3">)</span></span> && <span class="frag cond"><span class="openParen bm4">(</span><span class="frag">b</span>&lt;10<span class="closeParen bm4">)</span></span><span class="closeParen bm2">)</span></span> || <span class="frag">b</span>==15 <span class="closeParen bm1">)</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

(My system is like a code editor by the way, so i am using a contenteditable div) Here, i wanted to detect if im on the 3rd `b`.

[byossarian](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1937302/byossarian) has helped me with this:

```
var $elem = $('.frag').eq(fragNum);

var validAncest = $elem.parents('.cond').filter(function(i){
    return /^\s*(if|else\s+if)/.test($(this).text());
}).filter(function(i){
    var generations = 0,
    $elemCrawl = $('.frag').eq(fragNum);

    while ($elemCrawl[0] && $elemCrawl[0] !== this) {
        generations++;
        $elemCrawl = $elemCrawl.parent();
    }

    if ($elemCrawl[0] && generations < 4) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

finds all the ancestors of the element, it then filters then once to narrow down to those starting with 'if' or 'else if'. It then filters these to those that are either the parent, grandparent or great-grandparent (generations < 4) of the original element.

the condition to check will be:

```
if (validAncest.length && !$elem.nextAll('.frag').length) {
    alert('target acquired');
}
```

It checks that there is at least one valid ancestor (validAncest.length) AND that the original element is the last child of it's **IMMEDIATE parent** that has the class 'frag' (!$elem.nextAll('.frag').length)

**The problem**

IMMEDIATE parent should also be the last child/grandchild of the element with "if" or "else if"

So from the example above, the first `b` will already give me the alert where it should be on the 3rd `b`

**UPDATE** should pop the alert at the 2nd `b` not at `(b<10)`

[image]

Comment: when you say "IMMEDIATE parent should also be the last ... grandchild", what do you mean by last grandchild? do you mean last child of it's parent, or last child of the last child?

Comment: last child of the last child

Comment: and presumably it's fine if the immediate parent of the .frag element is the one with 'if'/'else if' at the start?

Comment: You mean if(b>0 && b<10)? it should alert at the 2nd b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `validAncest` with:

```
var validAncest = $elem.parents('.cond').filter(function(i){
    return /^\s*(if|else\s+if)/.test($(this).text());
}).filter(function(i){
    var generations = 1,
    $elemCrawl = $('.frag').eq(fragNum).parent();

    while ($elemCrawl[0] && $elemCrawl[0] !== this) {
        if (!$elemCrawl.is(':last-child')) {return false;}
        generations++;
        $elemCrawl = $elemCrawl.parent();
    }

    if ($elemCrawl[0] && generations < 4) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

This should include:

1. The parent of $elem provided it starts with 'if'/'else if'
2. The grandparent provided it starts with 'if'/'else if' AND the parent of $elem is the last child of this grandparent
3. The great-grandparent provided it starts with 'if'/'else if' AND the parent of $elem is the last child of the intermediate grandparent AND that grandparent is the last child of the great-grandparent

Comment: having: "if( (b>0) && (b<10) )" already triggers the alert at "(b<10)" wherein the alert should be triggered at the 2nd "b" using your answer

Comment: @extraRice I have it just detecting the last 'b': http://jsfiddle.net/BYoassrian/fNYzh/

Comment: its the exact HTML from mine right? hmm it could be on my side.. Thanks

Comment: @extraRice yeah, i just copied and pasted into JSFiddle.

Comment: I wanted to alert the parent of the target frag containing ang if or else if, how to do that?

Comment: @extraRice you mean if 'if' or 'else if' appears anywhere, not just at the start? you could use `/\bif\b/` since finding 'if' will also find 'else if'.